# sending array json object using FormData() to mvc controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to upload file to mvc controller using angular , everything works fine ,i get the file ,  even i have DTO as input parameter in my controller , it works fine , all members are binded by mvc except a member that is type of List .

here is my DTO

```
 public class UpdateMeetingInput 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Agenda { get; set; }
        public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }
        public List<AttendeeDto> Attendees {get;set;}
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is my javascript file

```
     var fd = new FormData();
                for (var key in meeting) {
// i will add attendees later                    
if (key != "attendees") {
                        fd.append(key, meeting[key])
                    }

                }
 fd.append('attendees', JSON.stringify(meeting.attendees));

$http.post("/meeting/update", fd, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            })
```

and here is my controller

```
 public class MeetingController : TransitControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMeetingManager _meetingManager;
        private readonly IRepository<Meeting, Guid> _meetingRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Decision> _decisionRepository;
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;


        public MeetingController (IMeetingManager meetingManager, IRepository<Meeting, Guid> meetingRepository, IRepository<Decision> decisionRepository, UserManager userManager)
        {
            _meetingManager = meetingManager;
            _meetingRepository = meetingRepository;
            _decisionRepository = decisionRepository;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public  async Task Update (UpdateMeetingInput input)
        {
```

i watch attendees value using rerquest.form.getvalue("attendees") and i get the following string that is correct , but i dont know why mvc cant bind it do dto

```
"[{\"userId\":0,\"name\":null,\"role\":\"4\",\"email\":\"someone@microsoft.com\",\"isGuest\":false,\"$$hashKey\":\"object:311\"}]"
```

am i doing something wrong in posting data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using **form data**, which **not** json, but JSON.stringify formats your list as json, which is not what the model binder expects.

To resolve this, you can make the attendees a string in the model, and then de-serialize it explicitly in the controller from JSON.

Alternatively, instead you could try to use special syntax, `attendees[]` as field name (note the square brackets), instead of `JSON.stringify`. Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < attendees.length; i++) {
    fd.append('attendees['+i+'][userId]', attendees[i].userId);
    fd.append('attendees['+i+'][name]', attendees[i].name);
    ....
}
```

Comment: i  de-serialize it explicitly in the controller from JSON.